# What is better? toggling visibility or manipulating text

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have a div with heading text like this:

```
<div class="vehicleCntr" id="vehicles">
    <div class="header">
        <h3 id="name"> Trucks </H3>
    </div>
```

The text in the heading H3 can take only 2 values: trucks or Cars. There will never be another value apart from these two. On click of cars hyperlink the heading has to change to 'Cars' and on click on trucks hyperlink the heading has to change to 'Trucks'.

Should I just remove the text of h3 and replace it everytime it is clicked or should I have 2 H3s like below and toggle the visibility:

```
 <div class="header">
        <h3 id="trucks"> Trucks </H3>
        <h3 id="cars"> Cars</H3>
    </div>
```

I am considering the performance benefits if any between these 2 methods. Since I assume it involves repaint and/OR reflow.

Comment: That has little to do with JS performance, it's all about browser (engine) performance.

Comment: Have you noticed this causing a performance bottleneck? Because if not, you're probably wasting time saving a millisecond or two.

Comment: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." ~~~ DonaldKnuth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A re-flow occurs each time, so I don't think there is much difference between the two. I would choose the second however since I wouldn't always have to add / remove new stuff in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should think about the semantics as well. Having two H3-tags that is saying different things will definitely confuse search engines and people using browsers that doesn't care about CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only way to prevent reflow would be to use `visibility:hidden` but then the element will still take up space on the screen. If you want to remove/hide it a reflow is required. I'd say `display:none` is your best shot then.

Edit: Code snippets above are CSS rules.

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach using `.text()` seems fastest: http://jsperf.com/text-vs-toggle

Though in the greater scheme of things, unless there are hundreds of elements changing,  trying to find the fastest seems like micro-optimization.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the performance difference isn't worth worrying about, so I'd choose based on other criteria. Specifically, I'd probably choose the second method, toggling visibility, so that if in future you wanted to change the formatting associated with each word you could define it all in the HTML/CSS and keep the JS simple - e.g., you might define a background picture associated with each word.